Using overlays and listings
My beamer presentation has a slide with some code on it which is presented with the lstlisting environment. A specific line should only appear on a second version of the slide (overlay). Basically, I want to do this:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Minimal Example}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,
                     escapeinside={<@}{@>}]
int a = 1;
<@\only<2->{int b = 2;}@>
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

However, with this, the line int b = 2 does not receive any syntax highlighting and uses the normal text font.
The question: How can overlay be used in a listing while preserving formatting?

You could use <@\onslide<2->@> before the line you want to uncover. In case this is not the last line and you want some later lines to visible from the start, you can switch back with <@\onslide<1->@>:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Minimal Example}
  \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,
                     escapeinside={<@}{@>}]
int a = 1;
<@\onslide<2->@>int b = 2;
<@\onslide<1->@>int a = 1;
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Very nice! In my actual problem, the listing also has frame=single, numbers=left,. If I apply your solution the line number of line three as well as a small part of the frame between the (missing) line number and int are not drawn. However, this can be fixed by moving <@\onslide<1->@> from the start of the next line to the end of the one that is only uncovered on slide 2! Maybe you want to include this in your solution :)
